# Extracting more than one date from a text field

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL query that I am using that works perfectly for what I am needing at extracting the *first* date in a text field.  This is a free form text field that is tied to a status that when the right conditions align my query looks for a date and if it is in the correct format it extracts this date.

Sometimes the date will be input as a range of dates or a comma separated list of dates.  I would like to know if there is a way to extract the last date in the case of a date range or the other dates in a list of dates?

The current query has 3 steps in temp tables for extracting the date here are snippets for each step.

In the first step it looks for the word 'proposed' and grabs a number of characters after:

```
,SUBSTRING(al.Comments,
    PATINDEX('%proposed%',al.Comments)+9,17)        [DateFirstPass]
```

In the second step the query it extracts the date:

```
,LEFT(
    SUBSTRING(p1.DateFirstPass, PATINDEX('%[0-9/]%', p1.DateFirstPass), 10), --string (only numbers and forward slash) MAX of 10 chars (mm/dd/yyyy)
            PATINDEX('%[^0-9/]%', SUBSTRING(p1.DateFirstPass, PATINDEX('%[0-9/]%', p1.DateFirstPass), 10) + 'X')-1) --char length after negating nonvalid characters '%[^0-9/]%'
                                                    [DateSecondPass]
```

In the last pass it adds in the year if it is missing:

```
    CASE    
        WHEN ISDATE(p2.DateSecondPass) = 1
        THEN CAST(p2.DateSecondPass AS DATE)
        WHEN ISDATE(p2.DateSecondPass + '/' + this.yr) = 1
        THEN p2.DateSecondPass + '/' + this.yr --Adds missing year
    END                                             [DateThirdPass]
    FROM
        #ProposedDateParse2 p2
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)))) this(yr)
```

Comment: For the date rage you could use the RIGHT function. For the list of dates you need to search for a string split function on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a copy of [patternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/)

Here's the code:

```
-- PatternSplitCM will split a string based on a pattern of the form 
-- supported by LIKE and PATINDEX 
-- 
-- Created by: Chris Morris 12-Oct-2012 
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternSplitCM
(
  @List               VARCHAR(8000) = NULL,
  @Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
      SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
       n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))

    SELECT
      ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
      Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
      [Matched]
     FROM (
      SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
      FROM numbers
      CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) y
     ) d
     GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper
```

**Solution against a variable:**

```
DECLARE @string varchar(8000) = 
'Blah blah 3/1/2017, 12/19/2018,1/2/2020,1111/11111/1111/111/111 blah blah';

SELECT TOP (1) Item
FROM dbo.patternSplitCM(@string, '[0-9/]')
WHERE [Matched] = 1 AND ISDATE(item) = 1
ORDER BY -ItemNumber;
```

Results:

```
item
------
1/2/2020
```

Example against a table:

```
DECLARE @table table (someid int identity, sometext varchar(1000));
INSERT @table(sometext) VALUES
('Blah blah 3/1/2017, 12/19/2018,1/2/2020,1111/11111/1111/111/111 blah blah'),
('Yada yada 1/1/12, 12/31/1999 call me at 555-1212!');

SELECT t.someid, getLastDate.Item
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) Item
  FROM dbo.patternSplitCM(t.sometext, '[0-9/]')
  WHERE [Matched] = 1 AND ISDATE(item) = 1
  ORDER BY -ItemNumber
) getLastDate;
```

Results:

```
someid      Item
----------- -----------
1           1/2/2020
2           12/31/1999
```